# How to update jquery in joomla 2.5?

Tags: jquery, joomla

Can anyone please tell me how I can update the jQuery version on a Joomla! website?

Is there a template I need to modify?

Many thanks

Comment: "The primary goal of Stack Overflow is to build an archive of questions and answers that are useful to people and situations beyond that of the original asker." @link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading / updating scripts is a good idea, just test first locally that everything works as before. Some older scripts may have compatibility problems with newer versions of jQuery.

**The basic steps are the following:**

- Find the name of your current template (from the admin backend)
- Locate the template folder inside `/templates/YOURTEMPLATENAME`
- inspect index.php and figure out if jQuery is loaded locally (like from `/templates/YOURTEMPLATENAME/js/jquery.js` or from a CDN like `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`).
- If it's locally download a copy of jQuery and replace the old jQuery file
- If it's loaded from a CDN, update the link

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I've searched the source in the templates folder but cannot find a reference. I can see lots of php, but no path to the js file.

Is there any other way I can update jquery?

Thanks again

Comment: I am not very sure why you can't find it. Check your website with Firebug, inspect it's contents and see from where it's loaded.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Can you please tell me how to do that in FB?

Comment: I can find references to the js file. As I cant find how the javascript is embedded - can I just copy and paste the latest version of jquery into the jquery1.5.2.js file?

Comment: You can. Searching inside the template for the string should point to the js file. Also post your template index file.

Comment: This might also be added through the setup.php, along with other widgets. From the template folder (where your index.php is), open the includes folder and edit the setup.php file. This was where my jQuery was being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that your template is loading jQuery at all? There is no requirement that a template load jQuery. If your template does not, then putting the new code in the old file is not going to do anything at all.

You are better of putting what ever code you are trying to make work in to a module/plugin that loads the version of jQuery you would like to use when you want to use it. It's not a good idea to load jQuery if you are not going to use it. It adds overhead and creates potential jScript conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has jQuery built in, so any reference to it in a template may cause conflicts. The system's copy of jQuery resides at media/jui/js/jquery.js.